# django form queryset choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

this is my model

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="product_variation") 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

this is my form:

```
class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES, coerce=int, label=_('Quantity'),widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control text-center'}))
    variation_select = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['variation_select'].queryset = Variation.objects.filter(i want to filter there by foreign key, product_id=product_id)
```

this is my views:

```
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'],)
        return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

i want to filter the variations by product, any suggestion?

Comment: Please share the *view* where you use this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `product_id` as a parameter to the form:

```
class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES, coerce=int, label=_('Quantity'),widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control text-center'}))
    variation_select = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Variation.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, product_id=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if product_id is not None:
            self.fields['variation_select'].queryset = Variation.objects.filter(
                product_id=product_id
            )
```

Then in the view, we can pass the `product_id` to the form both for the GET as for the POST request:

```
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST, post_id=post_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'],)
            return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
    else:
        form = CartAddProductForm(post_id=post_id)
    # …
```

Comment: name 'product_id' is not defined

Comment: @GuianaAnnimali: did you alter the parameters of the `__init__` method of the form? Please *edit* the question with the *full* traceback of the form.

Comment: yes, now i added, but have another error, TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset', i try to add to add queryset=None, i riceived this error=  
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_prefetch_related_lookups',

Comment: @GuianaAnnimali: see edit for the init of the `variation_select`.